# hide Gridview Column but get value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a GridView which I databind it on Page_Load(). I want to hide one its columns but i want to still have access to it. I tried

```
       SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select name,surname,id from test", sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();         
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;          
        GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.columns[1].visible= False;
```

And i get the error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you try making column width = 0? If you are getting error message at the time of setting the visibility, it could be the problem that your data source doesnt have 3 fields. Remember, it starts with index 0.

Comment: Might want to show more code - specifically, where and how you're databinding the control.  The error you're seeing almost certainly indicates that GridViewTest.columns has zero or one elements in it, at the point when you are trying to access the 2nd element.

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating columns when all you need to do is access the data. That's what data keys are for.

Comment: @mikemanne Check my code

Answer (score 2):

Use data keys for this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" ...>
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
       <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surname" DataField="Surname" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Once you add data keys, you can access the values like this:

```
 //returns the id at the first row
 int ID = GridView1.DataKeys[0]["ID"] as int;
```

Comment: Hm but at the second line of your code i  get the following error : Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: @pikk: See edited answer. Sorry, I forgot to assign the column value to a variable.

Comment: yea but this how can it will help me to hide the column but still access its value?

Comment: This will eliminate the need to have a hidden column, because you will be able to access the column value through the data key.

Comment: Yes but as you can see at my code i databind the column id. If i dont insert it inside the select statement how is it possible to get its value?!

Comment: Good Lord... you're still returning the column from the select. The only difference is that you're holding the value in a data key instead of hiding it in a column. The value will be easier to access this way. That's what data keys are for, and I suggest you do a little research on them to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.visible.aspx: "*..add the field name to the DataKeyNames property of the data-bound control*"